# syntax error in creating text column

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to use sqlite3 in python, and create a table with a column of long texts:

```
c.execute("create table essays (id varchar(255), projectid varchar(255), tid varchar(255), title text")
```

after that i have error:

```
OperationalError: near "text": syntax error
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the statement you're trying to execute is missing a closing parenthesis.

Looking at the statement alone it's easy to see

```
create table essays 
(id varchar(255), projectid varchar(255), tid varchar(255), title text
                                                                      ^ oops!
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the last parenthesis in the SQL expression:

```
c.execute("""\
    create table essays
        (id varchar(255),
         projectid varchar(255), 
         tid varchar(255), 
         title text)
    """)
```

The `)` after `title text` is required.